# How to local the correct xpath that gives me the url?

Tags: python, html, url, xpath

I am trying to scrape a few URLs via python. In particular, I am working on the link to the [Hong Kong election platforms](https://www.elections.gov.hk/dc2019/eng/intro_to_can/A.html). I used the inspect function that chrome provides, and I also used the etree function of lxml on python. I have located the xpath of the "text".

The code that I have used is

```py
 def extract_info_urls(self, response):
        raw_tree = etree.HTML(response)
        platform_urls = raw_tree.xpath('//*[@id="table-district-member"]/tbody/tr/td[6]/div/a/@href|//*[@id="table-district-member"]/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/a/@href')
        return platform_urls
```

The results look something like this:

```
../../pdf/intro_to_can/A01_1_ENG.html
```

With the above being said, my humble question is how can I obtain a full url - https://www.elections.gov.hk/dc2019/pdf/intro_to_can/A01_1_ENG.html -
instead of just a url starting with "../../pdf" in the results.

This is my first question here, and it might be dumb. But I appreicate all your help. Looking forward to learning from you all here!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get *full URL* you can replace

```
return platform_urls
```

with

```
return ["https://www.elections.gov.hk/dc2019/" + platform_url.lstrip("../..") for platform_url in platform_urls]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. It seems that the results remain the same - starting with "../../pdf". Any thought on it?

Comment: on traceback it says, File "/Users/WilliamLun/PycharmProjects/python101/biggie.py", line 24, in extract_info_urls
    return "https://www.elections.gov.hk/dc2019/" + platform_urls.lstrip("../..")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

Comment: the answer remains to be the same.

Comment: @WilliamL do you mean that script output remains the same?

Comment: yes, they still show as ../../pdf/intro_to_can/A01_1_ENG.html :(